# How to freeze a column in Grid and make it always shown in client area of a WPF user control

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I searched in stackoverflow, and there is a property FrozenColumnCount for DataGrid, but Grid control doesn't have that property.

We have a Grid with 2 columns. Now, we need to freeze the last column in a grid, and make it always shown in the client area of the user control. otherwise, if the data (such as text) in first column is too long, customer has to use mouse to drag the horizon scroll bar to show the 2nd column.

We want customer can always see the data in 2nd column, so I wonder if we could freeze the specified column.

[image]

Update 1: I paste my code for the tree view control.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Uid="HierarchicalDataTemplate_1" x:Key="MyPaletteMyTestTreeCell" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyTestDataAccessor}}" 
                                      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTestDataAccessor}">
    <ContentControl x:Uid="ContentControl_1" MouseDoubleClick="Item_MouseDoubleClick" ContextMenu="{StaticResource TreeListViewItemContextMenu}" MouseRightButtonDown="MRClick" Focusable="False">
        <Grid x:Uid="Grid_2" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Uid="ColumnDefinition_3" />
                <ColumnDefinition x:Uid="ColumnDefinition_2" Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Uid="Grid_3" Grid.Column="0">
                <StackPanel x:Uid="StackPanel_3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <pc:ThemedImage x:Uid="Image_4" 
                                LightSource="{Binding CategoryId, Converter={StaticResource LightMyTestIconConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                DarkSource="{Binding CategoryId, Converter={StaticResource DarkMyTestIconConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                Width="16" Height="16" 
                                Margin="0,1,0,1"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Uid="TextBlock_13" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0,0,1" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Uid="Grid_4" Grid.Column="1">
                <CheckBox x:Uid="CheckBox_3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="CheckBox_Click" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource MyPaletteMyTestVisibilityStyle}" ToolTip="On/Off" Focusable="False">
                    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                        <Binding x:Uid="Binding_1" Converter="{StaticResource MyTestDataAccessor}" Path="Visibility" Mode="OneWay">
                            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                <FrameworkElement x:Uid="FrameworkElement_1" DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}" Tag="Visibility"/>
                            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                        </Binding>
                    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                    <CheckBox.IsEnabled>
                        <Binding x:Uid="Binding_2" Converter="{StaticResource MyTestDataAccessor}" Path="Visibility" Mode="OneWay">
                            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                <FrameworkElement x:Uid="FrameworkElement_2" DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}" Tag="Enabled"/>
                            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                        </Binding>
                    </CheckBox.IsEnabled>
                </CheckBox>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentControl>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

SOLUTION:

I found the cause. I have specified a horizon scroll bar for it. 
So, when I removed it and use the code above, it can work as expected.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, you're not thinking about this correctly. You just need to put the column that you want to 'freeze' into a column of an outer `Grid`. Try something this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <!-- Your other controls -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Name="FrozenColumn">
        <!-- Your frozen controls -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I updated my thread and added the xaml code I used. I modified as what you suggest, but still got the same result. The horizon scroll bar still exist and the long word text was not Ellipsis. Any comments? thx.

Comment: You just need to learn how to use a `Grid` my friend. Setting `Width="Auto"` should only be used for content like your right column, that doesn't need so much space. You middle column with the text in should be set to `Width="*"`.